# Javascript not working in Android 4.0 WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have an android application which contains `HTML` pages, `CSS`, and `JavaScript`. `javaScript` files are placed into the `assets` directory of the android application. I have `WebView` to my layout to render these `HTML` files.

The application is running perfectly on other versions of Android but not running on Android 4.0. Following is the error line printed on logcat:

`E/Web Console(23096): Uncaught ReferenceError: [function_name] is not defined at null:1`

Could someone point me in right direction to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make the www directory inside the assets folder and place all the HTML pages, CSS, and JavaScript files

super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

Comment: can not place `html` and `css` files into assets folder as these needs to be generated dynamically